# Performance of django API view pagination

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am new to python django. I am using APIView. I am looking at pagination code. I have looked through many codes but in all those, i have a concern.

They all get all the data from the table and then paginate that data.

```
zones = Zone.objects.all()
paginator = Paginator(zones, 2)
page = 2
zones = paginator.page(page)
serializer = ZoneSerializer(zones, many=True)
return {"data": serializer.data, 'count': zones.paginator.count, "code": status.HTTP_200_OK, "message": 'OK'}
```

My expectation is that i don't get all the records and then paginate using paginator. Otherwise i will have to write my own code to handle it.

Comment: As mentioned by @enthusiast-martin, there is no database interaction until evaluation. Refer to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not true that it gets all the records from database.

Look at this ( using django shell ). Note the `LIMIT`:

```
from django.db import connection
from apps.question.models import Question
from django.core.paginator import Paginator

p = Paginator(Question.objects.all(),2)

print(connection.queries)
[]

p.page(1)[0] # Accessing one element in page

print(connection.queries)

[{'sql': 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "question"',
  'time': '0.001'},
 {'sql': 'SELECT <all fields> FROM "question" ORDER BY "question"."id" DESC  LIMIT 2',
  'time': '0.000'},
]
```

Note:  I  removed the list of all fields from the 2nd query so it fits nicely here.

Comment: But first line is zones = Zone.objects.all(), is it ignored and not executed until second line?

Comment: Thanks, i found the answer. It is mentioned in the documentation. Querysets are lazy and there is not database interaction until evalution. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy

Comment: @Sandhu No, you can see from the output that the first query when you construct the paginator is not executed immediately ( hence the empty list of connection queries). You can read in the docs when the querysets are evaluated.